# Flash AS2 - LoadMovie movieclip property edits don't show in browser

Tags: actionscript

Using loadmovie I'm loading an external SWF on a different domain. Any property changes made to a movie clip in the loaded SWF don't show in a broswer.

```
container.emc.loadMovie("http://externaldomain.com/movieA.swf");
```

Inside movieA is the movieclip "box". I don't want "box"  to be visible so I've used

```
container.emc.box._visible = false;
```

All working fine at this point, when I preview the SWF from Flash (CS3) I see that box isn't visible.

When I open the SWF in the browser, movieA is loaded but box is not set to invisible. This happens with all browsers or any publish settings I try.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a caching issue. A short term fix is to clear your cache and try again. A awy to prevent this from happening in the long term fix is to use a cache buster:

```
container.emc.loadMovie("http://externaldomain.com/movieA.swf"+ '?r=' + int(Math.random() * 100000);
```

Doing this forces the browser to refresh this file every time you request it.